# Prerequisites for running Kinect-enabled apps on end-user machine

Tags: c#, wpf, runtime, kinect

I have developed an application which uses a Kinect. The application has been developed using Visual Studio 2012 on an iMac running 64-bit Windows 7 Professional (using Bootcamp). I have used the `Publish Wizard` to create its setup. Now I need to make it work on any computer running 32/64 bit Windows 7. I have installed Kinect Runtime v1.5 setup on the end-user machine. Also, .NET Framework 4 Client is already installed on the end-user machine.

The problem is, using the `setup.exe` file created from the `Publish Wizard`, the application gets installed on the end-user machine. However when I try to launch it by double-clicking on the application file that gets placed in the `Start Menu`, nothing happens. Also, the application process is not running in the background. I checked it.

Also, I tried it on two different machines, both running 64-bit Windows 7. The same behavior was observed. When I tried to use that application on my iMac (by installing it using the setup files), it worked flawlessly.

What exactly is the problem and how do I resolve it?

Comment: You would need to supply the same version of the Kinect SDK your program uses and the .NET Framework that your program uses. I suggest you avoid using the `Publish Wizard` and create your own Setup.exe that installs everything your program requires yourself.

Comment: How do you suggest I create my own setup.exe file? Can you link me to some place where I can read it up?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounter problems with installer creation: I think you should install InstallShield LE and create a installer following these instructions. They are quite straighforward:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/cb88b2/simple-steps-to-create-setup-file-using-install-shield-le-fr/

IMPORTANT: you need Visual Studio, not Visual Studio EXPRESS.